# Selecting only the rows where dataframe times that where hourly ends in HH:00:00, with 00:00 being minutes and seconds?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a lot of data from a lot of different datasets with different time frames (hourly, every 5 minutes, and every minute). I decided to get all of the data on even times, and only want the data ending in YYYY:MM:DD HH:00:00 (I have decades of data on this).

I have tried a few different methods to filter out only the data I want:

df.loc[starting_row_value::value_to_skip_by] but unfortunately there is some missing data so I start off with the HH:00:00, but by the end in a few different frames it ends up being HH:00:05 or HH:00:55, so missing data is messing this solution up

I also tried `df[df.time_column[-5:] == 00:00]`, but that gives me:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers
```

with a few false values + Name: time, dtype: bool] of type Series

I've done a lot of looking, and couldn't find anything for filter by specific hours. Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do? Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: dtypes for reach dataframe are as follows:

```
DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)                object
MST                              object
Global PSP [W/m^2]              float64
Direct NIP [W/m^2]              float64
Reflected PSP [W/m^2]           float64
time                     datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Everything but the time column was kept as is, whereas I used the following code to create the dataframe columns

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)'] + ' ' +df['MST']
```

Comment: Please post your dataframe dtypes (df.types)

Comment: Sorry it took so long - I was getting familiar with the stack overflow formatting. I just edited the main post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are working with `pd.Timestamp` values, you could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    pd.to_datetime('2022-04-06 11:00:00'),
    pd.to_datetime('2022-04-06 11:00:05')
], columns=['time_column'])

idx1 = df['time_column'].dt.minute == 0
idx2 = df['time_column'].dt.second == 0
df2 = df[idx1 & idx2]
print(df2)
```

prints

| index | time_column |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-04-06 11:00:00 |

Comment: Wowwwwwww that worked beautifully - thanks for the save! Follow-up question - does idx1/2 mean anything specific to the to_datetime function, or are those just arbitrary variables? I did a quick search of pandas idx to see more information, but only found a bunch of examples using them rather than any explanation

Comment: Those are just intermediary variables, with no further meaning other than `idx1` is `True` where and only where minutes are `00`, `idx2` being `True` where and only where seconds are `00` and `idx1 & idx2` (logical and) is `True` where and only where both seconds and minutes are `00`, respectively.